# MyISAM table repair stuck in loop

Tags: mysql, myisam

my MyISAM table is broken (I know it's better to use Innodb), but now I need to fix this large table. 200GB

I have already tried the following options, but the table repair seems endless and the TMD file size exceeds 400 GB

```
myisamchk -r -f -v table --sort_buffer_size=14G 

REPAIR TABLE table USE_FRM
```

```
Found link that points at 138552885352 (outside data file) at 11620162676
Wrong bytesec: 117-114-101 at 3030228088; Skipped
Wrong bytesec: 112-108- 97 at 3030228108; Skipped
Wrong bytesec: 105-116-104 at 3030228128; Skipped
Wrong bytesec: 110- 46- 32 at 3030228148; Skipped
Found link that points at 138552885352 (outside data file) at 11620162676
Wrong bytesec: 117-114-101 at 3030228088; Skipped
Wrong bytesec: 112-108- 97 at 3030228108; Skipped
Wrong bytesec: 105-116-104 at 3030228128; Skipped
Wrong bytesec: 110- 46- 32 at 3030228148; Skipped
Found link that points at 138552885352 (outside data file) at 11620162676
Wrong bytesec: 117-114-101 at 3030228088; Skipped
Wrong bytesec: 112-108- 97 at 3030228108; Skipped
```

is it any chance to repair this table? maybe there are some other utilities?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Repairing Myisam Table when there was no additional Disk space & Table corrupted](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11352/repairing-myisam-table-when-there-was-no-additional-disk-space-table-corrupted)